# PowerBuilder web deployment

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder.net

I need to know if we could create web projects with Sybase PowerBuilder. For instance to add web pages, add links, text fields etc (and not Native form based projects).

Is this possible with Sybase powerbuilder, if so can i have some reading materials about this ?

note: I don't want to migrate a form based desktop application to Web.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create web applications with PowerBuilder, but you will need EAServer (a Java EE application server by Sybase) for the deployement.

Comment: Can you provide a tutorial that i could use to run a Hello World using EAServer ?

Comment: I was under the impression (although never tried it) that PB Web applications could be served from IIS as well.

Comment: @Illep - I think the PB12.5 docs have a decent 'Getting Started' section.